# How to take Core Data and Filter it with NSPredicate Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am currently learn and creating a basic decision app. The basics of the app is to take user input for a category they would like to do and then all the things that want to fill that category with.

Now I am wanting to display the results on a table view which works but I also what to click on each individual category that they recently used and be able to see the things that they placed under ever category. I was getting everything that was being save to the Core Data but now I am trying to use NSPredicate to filter out what I need. When I run the App there is nothing in the table view.

mainName I have passed in from a different view controller to capture and set what the name of the category was to help filter the data. I was trying to use it in the predicate as a filter.

I don't know if what I am doing is right but help would be great. This is independent study project I am doing to help finish my degree and everything I know is self taught so far. If what I have is completely wrong please tell me. This is just one of the hundreds of different ways I have tried to get this right.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return whats.count


}
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

    let Doing = whats[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = Doing.valueForKey("what") as? String


    return cell
}

 func loadData(){


    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate

    if let context = appDelegate?.managedObjectContext{

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Doing")
        let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "namesR.noun = '\(mainName)'")
        (whats as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(namePredicate)
        fetchRequest.predicate = namePredicate
        do {
           let results =
                try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            whats = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use `Core Data` in your `tableView` based app? You can use `NSFetchedResultsController` class and their `delegate` protocol methods. This class specially designed for a `tableView`!

[Official Documentation for `NSFetchedResultsController` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you're saying you have a Category entity and an Item entity with many Item for each Category. In that case, in the view controller where you want to display the Items, you need to have a Category variable to use in your predicate so that you only get back the Items associated with that Category.

```
class ItemsTableVC {

    var category: Category!

    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = []
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category == %@", self.category)
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.sharedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        return fetchedResultsController
    }()

}
```

Comment: It is giving me an error on the self.sharedContext why would that be?? It says there is no member 'sharedContext'  in the VC

Comment: Replace `self.sharedContext` with `self.context` referring to the context you have declared in your code. Or
`let context =  UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.sharedManagedObject`

Comment: Alright now it is saying that UIApplication doesn't have sharedApplication() even if i use let context = UIApplication.sharedApplication().sharedManagedObject

Comment: Break it out into two lines like you had before.
`let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate`

`let context = appDelegate?.managedObjectContext`

Comment: Okay and then the code you gave is going in the func loadData() that I had right?

Comment: Yes you can put it in your loadData method, but you don't have to put it in there. [Here's](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/03/05/displaying-data-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift/) a good tutorial on using `NSFetchedResultsController`